# Bulgaria to Armenia

Tags: driving, turkey, driving-licenses, georgia-country, armenia

We have a Bulgarian registered car and Bulgarian driving licences, but are Brits. Having seen the requirements for those travelling through to Georgia on a UK driving licence please could anybody inform us as to how to get as far as Armenia on Bulgarian licences?

Answer (score 2):

**Please remember: If you acquire an EU driving license (in this case Bulgaria), you need to live at least 185 days in Bulgaria and your blocking period in your home country must have expired. Driving licenses which violate this conditions are *invalid*! See EuGH 2012-04-26 Az. C-419/10 and the 3. driving license guideline 2006/126/EG**.

Your driving license is with the conditions above a normal EU driving license and will be acknowledged, so you only need to get an International Driving Permit and with those two documents you can travel normally by car.